# Deploying multiple Deis clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, deis

I am looking to create a number of Deis clusters running in parallel on AWS and haven't been able to find any good documentation on how to do so. From what I understand I'd have to do the following:

When provisioning the cluster:

- Create a new discovery URL
- Give the stack a different name other than the standard "deis" when using the ./provision-aws-cluster.sh script
- Create different Deis profiles in $HOME/.deis/client.json that map to each cluster

And when utilizing the deisctl and deis command line interfaces, I need to specify the DEISCTL_TUNNEL and the DEIS_PROFILE each time, respectively.

Am I missing anything? Will this impact my current Deis cluster if I install using the the changes listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, I don't believe you are missing anything.  You should save the cloud-config for each cluster (in contrib/coreos), that will have the discovery url in it and possibly other customizations depending on how your clusters will be configured.  If the clusters are going to be different on the AWS side, make sure you save the cloudformation.json file for each as well.